# How to translate my name

Tags: names, surnames, transliteration

I have seen many types of translation/transliteration of my Russian first and last names to English by different people. At the current moment I don't know what to choose when I want to introduce myself. 
So, my first name is `Вячеслав`

- Vyacheslav
- Viacheslav
- Vjacheslav

My last name is `Карбовничий`

- Karbovnichii
- Karbovnichiy
- Karbovnichij
- Karbovnichy

What is the best transliteration from the view of the native English language speaker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that [Molotov](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/molotov) is commonly transliterated as *Vyacheslav*, so I would suggest you follow this convention.

As for the last name, I would prefer *Karbovnichy* (or perhaps *Karbovnitchy*?) - based on, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Mayakovsky.

Comment: Not "Karbovnitchy". The last couple syllables would suggest a need to scratch.

Comment: @verbose True, but the pronunciation would be correct.

Comment: The pronunciation's correct anyway. CH means [tʃ], so adding a T is superfluous. I'd transliterate it _Vyacheslav Karbovnichy_ for English speakers.

Comment: @JohnLawler Some people will pronounce CH as SH. And some as KH. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyotr_Ilyich_Tchaikovsky

Comment: Using _ch_ to represent ч in the first name but _tch_ seems like it would be an annoying inconsistency to carry around. I don't think using _ch_ would lead to any problems that using _tch_ would solve: those who would be likely to pronounce _ch_ [ʃ] in an obviously Slavic name will probably stumble over the name as a whole anyway, and those who know enough to know that _ch_ represents [h] or [x] in Polish and Czech would be unlikely to not also recognise that this name is Russian, not Polish/Czech.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "* it would be an annoying inconsistency to carry around.*" Well, Pyotr Ilyi**ch Tch**aikovsky seems to have survived such burden. Fact is that there is no consistent pronunciation of *ch* nor is there a consistent transliteration of the sound (Czechoslovakia) - so at best one may express a preference, not exclude other options.